# How to recover home folder? Cloned partition recovered other directories like /etc/ but not /home

Tags: backup, partition, recovery, fsck

I have two linux partitions on my laptop (one ubuntu and one garuda). Ubuntu was giving me problems so I installed Garuda to check it out. The Garuda partition filled up so I used KDE partition manager to shrink the ubuntu partition so I could expand the Garuda.

Then, Ubuntu wouldn't mount and would not boot as it said the fs was wrong size. I ran fsck on the partition and hit yes to pretty much everything. This included force rewriting blocks it said it couldn't reach and removing inodes, etc. Probably a mistake in hindsight.

Now, I got a external hard drive and cloned the Ubuntu partition using "sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p5 of=/dev/sda1 conv=noerror,sync". The external hard drive mounted without problem but it does not have /home/ folder, only folders such as /etc/.

I don't think there's many files I cant get back from a git repo, but it would be nice to have access to the /home folder so I can grab everything, remove the ubuntu partition, and resize garuda.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I kind of followed https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129322/file-missing-after-fsck but

I copied the partition to an external drive using dd. Then mounted the external drive (which just worked even though I could not mount the original ubuntu partition). Then I went into the lost+found folder on the partition and used "find" to search for a file I know I had in my home folder and it found that file. I am not able to access all my documents etc.